# add or present view before launching first tab view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am making an iPhone app in which I have used both, the **navigation** as well as the **tabbar controller**. Now after splash screen I want to show a `UIView` before showing the first view controller of the tab bar.

Currently I have added one subview on first tabBar controller. But this view gets messed up with the first tabBar controller's view.

Can anyone tell me that is it possible to add or present a `UIView` before launching the tabBar controller? If anyone has an idea please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the storyboard. Make your additional view the first scene. Add a segue to the tab view. If you want an automatic transition, trigger the segue by a timer.